# Find N digit in a number

Tags: php

Say I have:

```
$n = 963205;
```

How can I find out what the second digit (`6`) is for example? Would it be a good idea to just cast to string and use `substr()`?

Comment: You don't need to cast to string, that will be done automatically.

Comment: What happened when you tried `substr()`? Didn't it work?

Comment: I'm not sure it's optimal.

Comment: afaik, `substr($n, 1, 1)` is a totally acceptable way to pull a single character out of a string.

Comment: @schmitsz optimal in what sense? The time difference between string manipulation and mathematical manipulation will not be noticeable unless you're doing this millions of times, but the two may be very different if you have to maintain this code. Generally, you should *optimize for readability*.

Comment: I mean, there should be a **simpler** solution that I'm missing.

Answer (score 2):

`substr` expects a string, and with some exception, PHP will normally convert to the correct type, so:

```
$result = substr($n, 1, 1);
```

Or if you still need an int:

```
$result = (int)substr($n, 1, 1);
```

Shouldn't really matter.  Doesn't get much simpler.  Did you want a regex?

Comment: There is a reason that `substr()` is named like that. I asked for a different solution as I do not consider this one acceptable.

Comment: There is a reason that it is acceptable, PHP is loosely typed.  If you don't like it use another.  What's "unacceptable" about it?  You didn't give any other info.  BTW, you are at this time at -3.

Comment: Downvoting doesn't change the subject.

Comment: Again, do you want a regex?  I can give you one.

Comment: No. I want something that involves pure arithmetics or just a more concise solution. For instance, I can get the last digit if I do `%10` but what happens if I want to get the 9th (or second digit as in OP)?

Comment: Try `963205 - 963199` or http://math.stackexchange.com/ for a better answer.  Why is this PHP?

Comment: Say I have the number `123`. Last digit would be `123%10`. Then I want to get the next digit (backwards, which is 2) so I have to remove the `3` and I divide by `3`.

Answer (score 1):

Just because using string processing to solve a math problem is ***wrong***:

```
function ndigit($in, $digit, $base=10) {
        // how many digits does 0 have?
        // alter the return here to fit your personal philosophy
        if( $in == 0 ) { return 0; }
        // algorithm doesn't work so good with negative numbers, just make it positive.
        if( $in < 0 ) { $in *= -1; }
        // length of the input number
        $len = (int)floor(log($in, $base)) + 1;
        // can't get 8th digit of a 7 digit number
        if( $digit > $len ) { throw new Exception('Supplied digit out of range.'); }
        // digit position counted from the right
        $rpos = $len - $digit;
        // zero out digits to the right
        $tmp = $in - ($in % pow($base, $rpos));
        // remove digits from the right and divide
        return ($tmp % pow($base, $rpos+1)) / pow($base, $rpos);
}

var_dump(ndigit(963205, 3)); // int(6)
```

You should be able to use this to find the *n*th digit of any number in any base. For example:

```
var_dump(ndigit(963205, 2, 16)); // int(11) aka B
```